# Is every positive $(n-1,n-1)$ form almost decomposable?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $(X,\omega)$ is a compact hermitian manifold of complex dimension $n$, and $\alpha$ is a smooth $(n-1,n-1)$ positive form, i.e., $\alpha = a \omega ^{n-1} + \displaystyle \sum _{i=1} ^m (\sqrt{-1})^n (-1)^{n(n-1)/2}f_i \Phi _i \wedge \bar{\Phi}_i$ where $a>0$ is a constant, $f_i \geq 0$ are smooth functions, and $\Phi_i$ are smooth $(n-1,0)$ forms. Then does there exist a hermitian metric $\chi$ such that $\alpha \wedge \gamma= \chi ^{n-1} \wedge \gamma $? for all hermitian metrics $\gamma$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you aren't asking for a $\chi$ such that $\alpha = \chi^{n-1}$, as this surely exists and doesn't require compactness.  The point is that $\alpha$ is positive by construction and, for any $n$-dimensional complex vector space $V$ with $n\ge 2$, the natural map
$$
p:\Lambda^{(1,1)}(V)\to \Lambda^{(n-1,n-1)}(V)
$$
defined by $p(\omega) = \omega^{n-1}$ induces a diffeomorphism 
$$
p:\Lambda^{(1,1)}_+(V)\to \Lambda^{(n-1,n-1)}_+(V)
$$
between the positive cones.